# Determining if there are unused packages in an R script

Tags: r

I obtained a large R script from a friend and am modifying it. The script calls lots of packages into play, but I know for a fact that not all of them are used in the body of the script. Is there a quick way to search through the script and determine which packages are used and which are not? Thanks!